# is there any static code analyzer which can catch this memory leak?

Tags: linux, memory-leaks, linux-kernel, coverity

Such leaks seem too trivial to naked eye and I think static code analysis tools should be able to find them out.

```
 Ex1:
 void foo(void) {
    u32 *ptr = kmalloc(512, GFP_KERNEL);
    ptr = (u32 *)0xffffffff;
    kfree(ptr);
 }
```

I know `Coverity` can find leaks as below but not sure about the above one: Can anyone please let me know if this will get detected in either `Coverity` or tools like `Sparse`?

```
Ex2:
void foo(void) {
    kmalloc(512, GFP_KERNEL);
}

Ex3:
void foo(void) {
    void * ptr = kmalloc(512, GFP_KERNEL);

    if (true)
        return;

    kfree(ptr)
}
```

Comment: Your example is simple.  There are two tacks.  Coverity and others attempt to dynamically ascertain rules about what a function does.  Some other tools (like Sparse, splint, etc) require annotations which capture the extra meaning (beyond the language).   [**Coccinelle**](http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/) could be written to detect the rules.  The tools may have meaning built-in.  [gcc __attribute()](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html), like *format*, *malloc*, *nonnull* could be or are examples of *annotations*.

Comment: There is also a leak detector in the kernel that will give a back-trace of the allocating caller; as an example of 'Valgrind' that actually works in kernel space.  Any of the tools above *could* possibly detect the errors.  Sometimes it is difficult to parse code; especially with inline assembler.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit how can `Covery/Sparse` will detect this memory leak. I know little bit about `sparse`, It can warn us with following message:
`u32 *ptr = kmalloc(512, GFP_KERNEL); ` it will report the `incorrect type assignment warning`. But  for this `ptr = (u32 *)0xffffffff;` will not report any warning as type casting is silencing the warning.  Then how can `Sparse` detec this memory leak ?
Please correct me if I am taking it wrong.

Comment: They track 'references'.  A 'malloc' type function must be stored in some variable(s).  If the checker/compiler see that a 'reference' becomes zero, you have a leak.  malloc/free must be annotated (recognized) as source/sink; the same with `kmalloc` and `kfree` or whatever allocation you use.  When you do `ptr = xxx`, if see that the only reference to the `kmalloc` memory is zero/dead and gives a warning.

Comment: `a 'reference' becomes zero, you have a leak.` please explain it. It would be really appreciable if you can explain it with given example. Thanks .

Comment: See: [Data flow at wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-flow_analysis), [Reaching definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaching_definition) and [google CFG liveness](https://www.google.ca/#q=control%20flow%20graph%20liveness).  It is how compilers work.  You just need to know if the 'return value of kmalloc()' seems useless; that handles this simple case.  The answer is very complex if you need full details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `kmalloc` (and I don't have a Linux system with a Coverity license to test that on), but Coverity detects leaks of this form with `malloc` easily. So I doubt kmalloc would give it trouble.

If it does give trouble, you can always provide a user model of the kmalloc function that just wraps around the malloc function so Coverity knows how to treat the function.

Answer (score -2):

[Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html) can be used to detect memory leaks mentioned in Ex1.

```
e.g. 
#include<stdio.h> 
void foo(void) {
    int *ptr = (int *)malloc(512);
    ptr = (int *)0xffffffff;
    free(ptr);
 }
int main(){
        foo();
        return 1;
}

Valigrind Output:

[test@myhost /tmp]# valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full ./Ex1
==23780== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==23780== Copyright (C) 2002-2009, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==23780== Using Valgrind-3.5.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==23780== Command: ./Ex1
==23780== 
==23780== Invalid free() / delete / delete[]
==23780==    at 0x4A05A31: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:325)
==23780==    by 0x400509: foo (in /tmp/Ex1)
==23780==    by 0x400514: main (in /tmp/Ex1)
==23780==  Address 0xffffffff is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==23780== 
==23780== 
==23780== HEAP SUMMARY:
==23780==     in use at exit: 512 bytes in 1 blocks
==23780==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 512 bytes allocated
==23780== 
==23780== 512 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==23780==    at 0x4A05E1C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==23780==    by 0x4004E9: foo (in /tmp/Ex1)
==23780==    by 0x400514: main (in /tmp/Ex1)
==23780== 
==23780== LEAK SUMMARY:
==23780==    definitely lost: 512 bytes in 1 blocks
==23780==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23780==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23780==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23780==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23780== 
==23780== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==23780== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

Comment: But Valgrind is not a **static** code analyser (they just "look" at the sourcecode). Valgrind **executes** the code!

Comment: I dobut.!!  Aplease notice as i have mentioned `kmalloc()` this is kernel address space, i think `Valgrind` can only address to user space memory leaks.